# Does Deadpool feel pain?

Tags: deadpool

I am a casual Deadpool fan, read a few comics played the game but was never to be considered a hardcore fan. We all know about deadpool's regeneration powers that enable him to survive virtually anything ranging from a bullet to the head to being cut in two.

[image]

My question is how can Deadpool still manage to throw puns left and right and speak casually even at the moment that his body should be experiencing excruciating pain all over his body cells ? I mean he'll survive once regenerated but at the time of receiving the blow his brain should be overwhelmed by the flood of messages through his neural system, even if we choose to say that is not enough to finish him off.

Comment: For you, this would be a traumatic, life-ending event.  If you were somehow unlucky enough to surive, it would remain ever a defining moment of your life.  For Deadpool, it is Tuesday.

Comment: I remember reading a Wolverine comic where he made the point that, once you've rebuilt your body from the molecular level, your threshold for "painful" is kind of irrevocably messed-up. I imagine Deadpool has a similar problem

Comment: I wouldn't qualify that as a problem @JasonBaker

Comment: I can't find the panels, but I'm fairly sure due to deadpool's nature his healing factor/cancers that he's in constant pain, and is part of what causes his madness.

Comment: @yondaime008 It's not a problem if you have Deadpool's level of healing. However, if you or I lost our ability to sense physical damage, it would be quite dangerous. The human body is fully capable of breaking its own bones/joints/ligaments. Often it's only our sense of pain that prevents us from causing more serious injuries to ourselves as well as allow ourselves time to recuperate from serious injuries or to even just seek medical attention.

Comment: Further to @Lèsemajesté's comment, the inability to feel pain is both problematic and a real thing (albeit rare) in humans (see the article on: "[*congenital insensitivity to pain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congenital_insensitivity_to_pain)" at Wikipedia.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Does he feel pain? Yes, absolutely.

[image]

Is it overwhelming? No, he appears to have a vastly diminished sense of pain.

[image]

Comment: I was looking for evidence of that diminished sense of pain actually. But it seems the matter wasn't tackled only mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, dead pool feels pain, but in the process of which he was made a mutant, he was put through insane pain causing his body to activate the mutant cell transformation. Because of this his body has built superhuman pain tolorence.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up this assertion?

Answer (score -1):

Of course!! He still been a human, his healing power just don't let him die (this and the curse Thanos put on him).
The little difference between him and Logan is because Logan is basically an animal, and this make him feel the pain kinda "different" of others humans.

[image]

That panel, from X-Men Origins: Deadpool, shows Wade in agony - and though he's playing it up to attract the attention of his guards, he yells out in pain earlier when he's shot.

[image]

In Deadpool Vol 3, #34, he tries a new version of the "pull my finger" trick, and we can see him feeling pain when he cuts his finger off.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up this assertion?

Comment: @Valorum about what? Deadpool feel pain/still been a human or about Wolverine feel the pain kinda different??