# Does Deadpool feel pain in the Deadpool movie

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, marvel, deadpool, deadpool-2016

### This is specifically a question for the Deadpool 2016 movie.

In this question,
[Does Deadpool feel pain?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103688/does-deadpool-feel-pain)
It is pretty clear that Deadpool feels pain:

[image]

But, in the movie he seems to not feel pain very much at all. In the below scenes, it shows him being shot at, cutting his arm off, breaking both hands and his leg and getting pounded by Colossus:

He looks like he may be in a bit trouble when Colossus hits him, but he just seems to be winded.

There was the scene with him getting a knife to the head, but he looks more disorientated than in pain, as he is daydreaming of making love with Vanessa.

Was there any in or out of universe explanation on Deadpool's pain threshold?

Comment: I thought he exclaimed in pain when he punched Colossus, but I may be misremembering.

Comment: I stated that in my question, but it looks more like he is winded and a few seconds later he is making jokes again.

Comment: sure, but he does at least yell in pain before quipping. I thought winded was when you get hit like in the stomach or chest and you feel like you can’t breathe.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, yeah, that what I was meaning to say. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

According to [Philip J. Silvera](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2856661/), the film's Stunt Coordinator, Wade can feel pain, but simply powers through it.

> **Q. In Deadpool, how you'd create that epic final battle between Wade Wilson and Ajax?**
>
> **PJS:** *Honestly, I think the workshop fight is the most brutal fight in that movie, but it was trimmed down because it was a little too violent, but you can watch it in deleted scenes. What was fun about that final Deadpool/Ajax scene is their differences. **Deadpool can feel pain and can’t die,** and Ajax can’t feel pain but can die. **You can see how one will shrug off pain and push through it,** and one doesn't feel it, but is actually getting hurt.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Chatting With Daredevil’s Emmy-Nominated Stunt Coordinator Philip J. Silvera](https://www.wheretowatch.com/2016/08/chatting-daredevil%E2%80%99s-emmy-nominated-stunt-coordinator-philip-j-silvera)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 3):

Deadpool does feel pain, but Deadpool is also *totally freaking insane*. He also knows that he's a character in a story, so he has a...different perspective on pain than other characters.

Remember Who Framed Roger Rabbit? "You could get out of these cuffs any time you wanted?" "Not any time. Only when it was funny!" Deadpool's pain threshold serves the needs of the plot.

Comment: I think you might be right. Can you provide some evidence from the movie to support this point, though?